# In BigQuery how to add a column to a manual partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table which we manually partitioned, same prefix but different suffix, each day a different table. For queries we work with wildcard.

Can I add a column to all the tables with the same prefix and if so how do you do that? I can't see to find a way to write a query that will add a column to all tables or any other way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: two questions: are you planning for refilling that new field in old tables? what is your pattern of querying those tables? (I mean FROM part of queries)

Comment: no just need it for new dates,but is it possible to update just new tables and not the old ones, will the queries still work?  the problem is my query uses wildcards in order to access multiple tables - multiple dates, so it could be the query will run on tables that have the new field and some that don't

Answer (score 0):

Adding column on BigQuery can be done via Web UI, cli or API. See [this section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#update-schema).

Comment: i need to add to multiple tables not one!

Answer (score 0):

> need it for new dates,but is it possible to update just new tables and not the old ones, will the queries still work?

Just make sure new column(s) is in your new tables and your **old queries** should still work

Please note: if you will modify your query to involve that new field - you will need to be sure that at least one new table (with new field) is part of your wildcard query. Otherwise you will get error - `Unrecognized name: yourNewField at [line:pos]`

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i saw that happens. i gogoled a lot and can't find a solution, how can i add a column to multiple tables ~900, with one script, i need to add to all the manual partitioned table the same column, will be null. Any idea?

Comment: you cannot do this with one call. you just need to write script in any language of your [choice](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: i tried to find examples,but can't. i saw you link and also this link https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-table-in-google-bigquery/ but i don't get it. I am using C#.

Comment: the plan for you is to 1) find/develop code that updates [one] table's schema by adding one or more fields 2) enhance code by adding looping through tables list one-by-one by applying script in 1) - good luck